# Electrostatic field and potential

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields

At different places, I saw the different signs in the relation of electrostatic field and potential:

$E=-\nabla \phi$ and $E=\nabla \phi$.

I am confusing what situations they are describing. For example, when the field lines point to +y, which one I should use?

Comment: Where have you seen $\mathbf{E}=\boldsymbol{\nabla}\phi$?

Comment: @Sebastiano i tried to find that but cannot here and now. Just confused when I saw the relation with a minus sign. I guess the sign convention may be related to the coordinate system and the direction of the field?

Comment: For my humble opinion the answer is no.

Comment: In general a scalar potential can be defined with or without the negative, but conventionally it is with the negative. In electrostatics, the electric potential always has a negative.

Comment: @SamGallagher did you mean the electric potential always has a negative irrespective of the coordinate system and the direction of the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative sign has physical meaning, it is related to

$$W=-\int_a^b\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{\ell}$$

When $\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E}=\vec{0}$, the electric force is conservative and you can define a potential energy from the force. Just as the electric field is a force per unit charge, the potential is a potential energy per unit charge; i.e.

$$V(\vec{r})=-\int_\mathcal{O}^\vec{r}\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{\ell}$$

where $\mathcal{O}$ is some reference point. If you move a positive test charge against an electric field, you should be increasing its potential energy. Hence the negative sign. The integral above can be undone with a gradient; i.e. $\vec{E}=-\vec{\nabla}V$.